# Can't use installed packages in GoLand

Tags: windows, go, goland

I'm using Go 1.16 and GoLand 2020.3.2.

If I type `import "github.com/a/b"`, GoLand will ask me to install the package.  I click install and it does so successfully.  The library is installed under `C:\Users\user\go\pkg\mod`.  But GoLand looks for the package in `C:\Users\user\go\go1.16\src`.

This my GOPATH `C:\Users\user\go` and GOROOT `C:\Users\user\go\go1.16`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try `go mod vendor`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with GoLand's handling of GOPATH based projects.

I created a [ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-10639) for this on our tracker.

As a workaround, you can create a `go.mod` file or a project based on `Go Modules` instead and the problem will be solved.